# There is no UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage in editingInfo even when allowsEditing is true

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to get the edited image from UIImagePickerController, but there is no UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage key in the editingInfo dictionary. What's wrong?

```
let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
pickerController.delegate = self
pickerController.allowsEditing = true
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    println(editingInfo)
    if let editedImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

    }
}
```

editingInfo outputs

```
[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage: <UIImage: 0x7f8f15a1f0e0> size {1500, 1001} orientation 0 scale 1.000000, UIImagePickerControllerCropRect: NSRect: {{994, 514}, {501, 487}}, UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=900A4F75-A88F-4332-AAC8-2BD3A2B1514A&ext=JPG]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)`, which is deprecated.

Use `func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])` instead!

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice that. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    self.imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```